# Multiple assignments of items of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment, items

Suppose to have a list of items and two lists of indexes that are parametric and for example are:

```
l={2,3,5,7,11,13,17}
i1={3,4,7}
i2={4,7,3}
```

I need a clever code to execute:

```
{l[[3]],l[[4]],l[[7]]}={l[[4]],l[[7]],l[[3]]}
```

so that the value of l will be:

```
{2,3,7,17,11,13,5}
```

Comment: Simply write: `l[[i1]] = l[[i2]];`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};

i1 = {3, 4, 7};
i2 = {4, 7, 3};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
list = SubsetMap[list[[i2]] &, list, i1]
```

{2, 3, 7, 17, 11, 13, 5}

Using `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

```
list //= SubsetMap[list[[i2]] &, i1]
```

{2, 3, 7, 17, 11, 13, 5}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};

i1 = {3, 4, 7};
i2 = {4, 7, 3};
```

---

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list, Thread[i1 -> list[[i2]]]]

(*{2, 3, 7, 17, 11, 13, 5}*)
```